# Fixing conflicting dependency

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, package-management, updates

Currently Running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Optiplex with an i5 660

I'm running into issues that *look* like a dependency conflict but I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the output correctly. Can someone please help me understand what I'm looking at and help me fix it?

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  


Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwinpr-heap0.1 : Depends: libc6 (= .= 2.2.5) but 2.23-0ubuntu5 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
humberto@DellServer:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libwinpr-heap0.1
Suggested packages:
  freerdp-x11
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libwinpr-heap0.1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 16.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libwinpr-heap0.1 amd64 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 [16.3 kB]
Fetched 16.3 kB in 0s (49.5 kB/s)           
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 16472 package 'libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64':
 error in 'Version' field string '7:".8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1': version number does not start with digit
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 16536 package 'libc6:i386':
 missing description
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 16580 package 'libwinpr-heap0.1:amd64':
 'Depends' field, reference to 'libc6':
 implicit exact match on version number, suggest using '=' instead
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 16580 package 'libwinpr-heap0.1:amd64':
 'Depends' field, reference to 'libc6':
 version value starts with non-alphanumeric, suggest adding a space
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 16580 package 'libwinpr-heap0.1:amd64':
 'Depends' field, reference to 'libc6': version contains ' '
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: It looks to me like a corrupted `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file (causing `dpkg` to think that `libwinpr-heap0.1` depends on a - beyond ancient - exact version 2.2.5 of `libc6`)

Comment: Should I delete it? What would be the appropriate way to fix this without breaking anything?

Comment: How long have you had this issue? you may be able to use the `status-old` file e.g. `sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status{,.broken}` then `sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status{-old,}` or from one of the backups `/var/backups/dpkg.status.0`, `/var/backups/dpkg.status.1.gz` etc.

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to give that a shot and see what happens

Comment: Thank you steeldriver that solved it! I've had the issue for a couple says and waan't sure what program installation did it. It may have been obs-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long have you had this issue? you may be able to use the status-old file e.g. sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status{,.broken} then sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status{-old,} or from one of the backups /var/backups/dpkg.status.0, /var/backups/dpkg.status.1.gz etc. – steeldriver 3 hours ago